# Username in URL for Django DeleteUser

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I want to use username in django url how i use can you tell me i am not using  yet  that time i used occure page not found error.

In my template

```
 template.html
    <a href="/accounts/{{ user.username }}/delete/">Delete</a>
```

In my urls

```
urls.py
    path('<str:username>/delete/', views.delete_user, name='delete_user'),
```

In my views

```
views.py

def delete_user(request, username):
    context = {}
    u = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    u.delete()
    messages.success(request,'your account delete')
    return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<a href="{% url 'delete_user' username=user.username %}">Delete</a>
```

That being said, deleting a user is a side effect. According to the HTTP standard, a [*GET* request is not supposed to have side-effects](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3). Therefore you probably should turn this in a POST request.